# Extra new line after itemizing

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, moderncv

I was writing my CV using this template from shareLatex https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-oldstyle.

```
\section{Food}\section{Food}
\cvitem{AA}{\begin{itemize}
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx  ae ra wer awer awe r awer 
\end{itemize}}
\cvitem{BB}{\begin{itemize}
\item efuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx  ddd oghcghvho gftudf ogdftftu fgyugvghcv
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\end{itemize}}%
```

The output look like this. Is there any way that I can remove the blank line between two sections in the middle? Try not to use `vspace` or something to force it.
[image]

Comment: The title of your question ("Extra new line after a") seems to be a work in progress :)

Comment: Change the vertical space after `\cvitem` where it's defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you added to your question shows that you are using style `classic` instead of `oldstyle`.

The relevant definition of `\cvitem` is:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

That means you can add an negative baseskip as optional parameter to get rid of the empty line:

```
\cvitem[-\baselineskip]{AA}{\begin{itemize} % <====================================
```

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % oldstyle
\moderncvcolor{grey}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image}
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Food}
\cvitem[-\baselineskip]{AA}{\begin{itemize} % <====================================
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx  ae ra wer awer awe r awer 
\end{itemize}}
\cvitem{BB}{\begin{itemize}
\item efuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx  ddd oghcghvho gftudf ogdftftu fgyugvghcv
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\item aefefuh huih huih huhi hiu huiyfuyfg gyguy guygg uig serdyov soujdfzx gydfx 
\end{itemize}}%

\end{document}
```

you get what you want:

[image]